# Keras model uses only one GPU all the time

Tags: python, tensorflow, amazon-ec2, keras

I am trying to train a CNN model on AWS EC2 p3.16xlarge instance which has 8 GPUs. When I use the batch size of 500,  even though the system has 8 GPUs, only one GPU is utilized all the time. When I increased the batch size to 1000, it uses only GPU and really slows compared to 500 case. If I increase the batch size to 2000, then a memory overflow occurs. How can I fix this issue?

I am using tensorflow backend. GPU utilization is as below,

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 410.104      Driver Version: 410.104      CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:00:17.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   47C    P0    69W / 300W |  15646MiB / 16130MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:00:18.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   44C    P0    59W / 300W |    502MiB / 16130MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:00:19.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   45C    P0    61W / 300W |    502MiB / 16130MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:00:1A.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   47C    P0    64W / 300W |    502MiB / 16130MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   4  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:00:1B.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   48C    P0    62W / 300W |    502MiB / 16130MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   5  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:00:1C.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   46C    P0    61W / 300W |    502MiB / 16130MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   6  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:00:1D.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   46C    P0    65W / 300W |    502MiB / 16130MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   7  Tesla V100-SXM2...  On   | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   46C    P0    63W / 300W |    502MiB / 16130MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0     15745      C   python3                                    15635MiB |
|    1     15745      C   python3                                      491MiB |
|    2     15745      C   python3                                      491MiB |
|    3     15745      C   python3                                      491MiB |
|    4     15745      C   python3                                      491MiB |
|    5     15745      C   python3                                      491MiB |
|    6     15745      C   python3                                      491MiB |
|    7     15745      C   python3                                      491MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for `multiple_gpu_model`. You can see that in the [keras documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-run-a-keras-model-on-multiple-gpus).

You can just take your model and do `parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=n_gpus)`.

Next time don't forget to include a [minimal working exemple](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).